# I can't access a list after query in a one-to-many relation with Hibernate and Criteria

Tags: hibernate, list, criteria, one-to-many

I have a problem with Hibernate, one-to-many associations and lists. In my model, I have countries and, for each country, I have multiple information describing a structure for addresses in that country. I want to access the list of these elements.

This my class Country :

```
public class Country {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private List<AddressElement> addressElementList = null;
  ...
}
```

My class AddressElement:

```
public class AddressElement {
  private Long id;
  private int pos;
  private int line;
  private String name;
  private String mask;
  ...
}
```

And my mappings :

```
<hibernate-mapping  package="org.devtutos.tuto5.domaine">
  <class  name="Country" table="tuto.COUNTRY">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="COUNTRY_ID" unsaved-value="null">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">tuto.SEQ_COUNTRY</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <natural-id mutable="true">
      <property name="name" column="COUNTRY_NAME" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </natural-id>
    <list name="addressElementList" table="tuto.ADDRESS_ELEMENT" lazy="false">
      <key  foreign-key="country_address_element_fk">
        <column name="COUNTRY_ID" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <list-index>
        <column name="ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS" not-null="true" />
      </list-index>
      <one-to-many class="AddressElement"/>
    </list>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
<hibernate-mapping  package="org.devtutos.tuto5.domaine">
  <class name="AddressElement" table="tuto.ADDRESS_ELEMENT">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ADDRESS_ELEMENT_ID" unsaved-value="null">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">tuto.SEQ_ADDRESS_ELEMENT</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="line" column="ADDRESS_ELEMENT_LINE" not-null="true" type="java.lang.Integer" />
    <property name="name" column="ADDRESS_ELEMENT_NAME" not-null="true" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="mask" column="ADDRESS_ELEMENT_TYPE_MASK" not-null="true" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="pos" column="ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS" not-null="true" type="java.lang.Integer" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This my code:

```
criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Country.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", countryName));
criteria.setFetchMode("addressElementList",FetchMode.JOIN);
Country country = (Country) criteria.list().get(0);
if (country == null) {
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "ERREUR DE COHERENCE INTERNE : Pays '".concat(countryName).concat("'non trouvé:"));
} else {
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Pays trouvé.");
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Nom du Pays :".concat(country.getName()));
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Code du Pays :".concat(String.valueOf(country.getId())));
  liste = country.getAddressElementList();
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Taille de la liste des éléments d'adresse :".concat(String.valueOf(liste.size())));
  for (AddressElement elem : liste) {
    if (elem == null) {logger.log(Level.INFO, "L'élément d'adresse est null.");}
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Element de la liste : ID = ".concat(String.valueOf(elem.getId())));    **** Line of the error
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Element de la liste : POS = ".concat(String.valueOf(elem.getPos())));
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Element de la liste : NOM = ".concat(elem.getName()));
  }
}
```

This is my log :

```
Hibernate: 
select 
this_.COUNTRY_ID as COUNTRY1_2_1_, 
this_.COUNTRY_NAME as COUNTRY2_2_1_, 
addressele2_.COUNTRY_ID as COUNTRY6_2_3_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_ID as ADDRESS1_3_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS as ADDRESS5_3_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_ID as ADDRESS1_0_0_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_LINE as ADDRESS2_0_0_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_NAME as ADDRESS3_0_0_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_TYPE_MASK as ADDRESS4_0_0_, 
addressele2_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS as ADDRESS5_0_0_ 
from 
tuto.COUNTRY this_ left outer join tuto.ADDRESS_ELEMENT addressele2_ 
on this_.COUNTRY_ID=addressele2_.COUNTRY_ID 
where 
this_.COUNTRY_NAME=?
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Pays trouvé.
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Nom du Pays :FRANCE
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Code du Pays :1
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Taille de la liste des éléments d'adresse :4
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: L'élément d'adresse est null.
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [tuto5] in context with path [/tuto-5] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@3f610944 targetAction org.devtutos.tuto5.mvc.webflow.action.receptionAction@4dc6bbd3, attributes = map['method' -> 'enregistrerLUtilisateur']] in state 'enregistrerLUtilisateur' of flow 'reception' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate.getCountryByName(CountryHibernate.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
...
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I can't access the information of address elements from a country. I tried several things: I turned on lazy mode and specified a fetch mode with JOIN but it doesn't work. The most surprising is the list is populated (there are 4 elements) and the following code runs well (So, the information is in the database, setters and getters work):

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Lecture de tous les éléments d'adresse.");
criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AddressElement.class);
liste = criteria.list();
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Taille de la liste des éléments d'adresse : ".concat(String.valueOf(liste.size())));
for (AddressElement elem : liste){
  if (elem == null) {logger.log(Level.INFO, "L'élément d'adresse est null.");}
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Element de la liste : ID = ".concat(String.valueOf(elem.getId())));
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Element de la liste : POS = ".concat(String.valueOf(elem.getPos())));
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Element de la liste : NOM = ".concat(elem.getName()));
}
```

These is the result of this code:

```
INFO: Lecture de tous les éléments d'adresse.
Hibernate: select this_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_ID as ADDRESS1_0_0_, this_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_LINE as ADDRESS2_0_0_, this_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_NAME as ADDRESS3_0_0_, this_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_TYPE_MASK as ADDRESS4_0_0_, this_.ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS as ADDRESS5_0_0_ from tuto.ADDRESS_ELEMENT this_
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Taille de la liste des éléments d'adresse : 6
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : ID = 1
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : POS = 1
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : NOM = Code Postal
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : ID = 2
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : POS = 2
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : NOM = Ville
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : ID = 3
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : POS = 3
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : NOM = Batiment
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : ID = 4
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : POS = 1
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : NOM = District
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : ID = 5
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : POS = 2
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : NOM = Zone
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : ID = 6
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : POS = 1
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
INFO: Element de la liste : NOM = City
27 déc. 2012 16:19:09 org.devtutos.tuto5.dao.CountryHibernate getCountryByName
```

I noticed in my first execution that the size of my list is wrong (4 instead of 3). In my example, the value of `countryName` is "FRANCE". This is the content of my tables:

COUNTRY:

```
COUNTRY_ID      CONTRY_NAME 
1                    "FRANCE"
2                    "HYPERION"
3                    "ATLANTIS"
```

ADDRESS_ELEMENT:

```
ADDRESS_ELEMENT_ID      COUNTRY_ID       ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS    ADDRESS_ELEMENT_NAME        ADDRESS_ELEMENT_MASK    ADDRESS_ELEMENT_LINE
1                       1               1                       "Code Postal"               "\d{5}"                 1
2                       1               2                       "Ville"                     "[A-Z\-]{1,50}"         1
3                       1               3                       "Batiment"                  "[A-F]"                 1
4                       2               1                       "District"                  "[A-Z]{1,20}"           1 
5                       2               2                       "Zone"                      "[A-5]{1,5}"            2
6                       3               1                       "City"                      "[A-Z]{1,9}"            1
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why `elem` is null in the first execution. Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Have a happy new year. ;-)

Comment: Show us the complete code of the Country entity.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

This is the complete code for the Country entity. There is only getters and setters. hashCode() and equals(Object obj) methods have been automatically by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is indexed by the column `ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS`. So if Hibernate loads all the list of addresses for the country `1`, it will set the address `1` at index 1 (since it's the value of `ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS` for this address), the address `2` at index 2, and the addres 3 at index 3. And since there is no address with `ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS = 0`, the index 0 of the list will be null.

Subtract 1 to the values of your ADDRESS_ELEMENT_POS in the database, or add the following attribute the the `list-index` configuration element: `base="1"`. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e10924.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

This is the complete code for the Country entity. There is only getters and setters. hashCode() and equals(Object obj) methods have been automatically by Eclipse.

```
package org.devtutos.tuto5.domaine;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Country {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<AddressElement> addressElementList = null;

    public Country(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }  

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public void addAddressElement( int pos, int line, String name, String mask){
        addressElementList.add(new AddressElement(pos,line,name,mask));
    }

    public List<AddressElement> getAddressElementList() {
        return addressElementList;
    }

    public void setAddressElementList(List<AddressElement> addressElementList) {
        this.addressElementList = addressElementList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
             return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Country other = (Country) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't where is the problem.
Thanks again...

Comment: Don't add this as an answer. It's not one. Click the edit link at the bottom of your question, and add the code to your question.